# Why CPU usage of my Asp.net often is about 25%

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, cpu-usage

I have a ASP.Net project and many reports.Some of my reports have heavy calculation that I calculate them in memory using Linq. When I test this reports on my client CPU usage is about 25%.

[image: Task Manager]

My question is why cpu usage does not increase to 80% or more?

When I publish this project on the server does it has this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 4 cores (or 2 hyper-threader cores), meaning each single thread can take up to 25% of the total computing power (which is shown as 25% CPU in the Task Manager).

Your calculation is probably single threaded.

Comment: Nothing. One thread can use one core. One core is (in your case) 25% of your CPU. If you want to use more cores, you run more threads.

Comment: Get an older CPU? You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly break your calculation into several threads? That'll spread the load across the cores of your CPU a little more evenly.